# If $X>0$ almost surely then is $ EX>0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X>0$ almost surely then is $ EX>0$? Can I conclude this using  the linearity of expectation ? With a greater than equal sign it indeed holds. But I can’t show it in this case . How could I show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a nonnegative $X$, $\mathsf{E}X=0$ iff $X=0$ a.s. Therefore, $\mathsf{E}X>0$ as long as $\mathsf{P}(X>0)>0$.

Comment: Yep.  The usual proof is to consider the events $A_n = \{X > 1/n\}$.  If $\mathsf{P}(A_n) > 0$ for some $n$, you conclude $\mathsf{E}[X] \ge \frac{1}{n} \mathsf{P}(A_n) > 0$, and if they all have probability zero, then by countable additivity you conclude that $X = 0$ a.s.